# Request all titles by actor using LINQ to Netflix OData

Tags: linq, odata, netflix

I'm experimenting with LINQPad to use LINQ to query the Netflix OData. I'm trying to search for all films with a particular actor in. For example:

```
from t in Titles 
from p in t.Cast
where p.Name == "Morgan Freeman"
select t.Name
```

this results in:

> NotSupportedException: Can only project the last entity type in the query being translated

I also tried:

```
from p in People
from t in p.TitlesActedIn
where p.Name == "Morgan Freeman"
select t.Name
```

which results in the following error:

> NotSupportedException: The method 'Select' is not supported

I've tried a few other approaches, such as using Id's in the where clause, and selecting different things, but have got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either this:

```
from p in People
where p.Id == 190
from t in p.TitlesActedIn
select new { Name = t.Name }
```

But note that this requires you not specify the Id, this translates to:
/People(190)/TitlesActedIn?$select=Name

If you need to filter based on non-key properties, you need to do something like:

```
from p in People
where p.Name == "Morgan Freeman"
select new Person {
    TitlesActedIn = p.TitlesActedIn
}
```

This translates to:
/People?$filter=Name eq 'Morgan Freeman'&$expand=TitlesActedIn

You could also just ask for the names of those titles, but LinqPad doesn't seem to have a way to do that, due to the type of properties it generates. It would look like:

```
from p in People
where p.Name == "Morgan Freeman"
select new Person {
    TitlesActedIn = p.TitlesActedIn.Select(t => new Title { Name = t.Name })
}
```

Which would translate to:
/People?$filter=Name eq 'Morgan Freeman'&$expand=TitlesActedIn&$select=TitlesActedIn/Name

Thanks,
Vitek Karas [MSFT]

Comment: thanks. I tried your third suggestion but it had an invalid cast error. I got it working with the following LINQ:
    from p in People
    where p.Name == "Morgan Freeman"
    select new {
 TitlesActedIn = p.TitlesActedIn.Select(t => t.Name)
    }